# The usage of "COME" in these sentences

Tags: past-participles

These are original sentences uttered by natives.

> 1 There are some very rare birds **come** by here.
>
> 2 You are a poor boy from Ireland **come** to London.

I wonder what COME means in them. According to the context I infer that:

> 1 There are some very rare birds come by here. = There are some very
> rare birds which come by here.
>
> 2 You are a poor boy from Ireland come to London. = You are a poor boy
> from Ireland who has come to London.

Comment: Which natives? Did you hear them say it, or are they fictional characters in books?

Comment: They say that on video

Comment: What video? Link please.

Comment: What's the reason? Are you challenging the correctness of the sentences?

Comment: Did you take offence? Shame.

Comment: @user1425 It seems you took offence when you were asked to provide the information needed to answer your question. It sounds a bit old-fashioned to me, maybe dialect, so knowing where it comes from would be very useful.

Comment: I didn't take offence, I just asked for a good reason. If you give me a good reason I will point at the provenance. Downvoting my question is taking offence. I can only say for now that both sentences are from the 21 century.

Comment: Vandalising your own posts is never a good idea, and it is rude especially when someone has spent time composing an answer.

Comment: Providing the source is a courteous act, and attributing the author (if it's from a script or novel) is absolutely necessary. it is interesting to know where you heard these utterances and who spoke them. You are not a native speaker, so it's likely you misheard. It's nothing to be ashamed or embarrassed about. I mishear lyrics and many movie lines all the time.

Comment: Actually, I had provided the provenance before I realized that it was ignored and no one commented on it. So, I deleted it. I think people who downvoted my BRILLIANT question don't deserve to see this question at all. The only reason why they were asking for the video is to humiliate me as if I were dumb. On top of that, the expertise of such people is very dubious as they find these absolutely legit sentences wrong.

Comment: *"I think people who downvoted my BRILLIANT question..."* Wait. Mr... Mr Trump? Is that you? Seriously though. @MichaelHarvey is an established contributor to ELL, who regularly provides thoughtful and informative answers. As far as I can see, he was just asking for more info -- TO HELP YOU -- nothing more. The fact that he has, classily, desisted from rebuking you given your subsequent comments (which, to any objective observer look *remarkably* like someone taking offence) is further evidence that he wasn't being in any way nasty.

Comment: tkp Oh really? So, if he is such a top-notch contributor, where is his contribution in the form of an answer to this question? I don't need help from the people who I must help in order for them to help me. It smells like swindling.

Comment: @tkp - I thank you for your kind words! I have to decline the 'classy' compliment, though, since my lack of response was (is) due to not knowing about this set of comments. I have decided that issuing stern rebukes seldom does much good, but this stance is more a practical one (to avoid needless clutter) than an example of good breeding.

Comment: @tkp - it is interesting to know I that I am 'established' - like the Church of England?

Comment: Exactly. Or perhaps like the village blacksmith business. Been around for generations, in the same family and passed from father to son (cos that’s how they did it in the olden days), and with a sign over the door saying “Est. 1826”

Comment: These are two different dialectal uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems casual, possibly dialect, or possibly just an individual lazily omitting words.

In both cases I interpret the clause containing "come" to be a relative clause.  I agree with your insertion of "which" and "who has".

The ambiguity arises because the past participle of "come"  is "come".

"Come by" is similar in meaning to "pass by".  The birds come, and then pass by.

However, since the correctness of these sentences is questionable.  The relative subordinator might be greatly reduced in pronunciation from "that" to "/ut/" or even with a schwa and glottal-stop, and so might not be heard or transcribed (this is more likely in some dialects). Or a dialect might use "as" as a relativiser. Without access to the video, further analysis does not seem possible.

Comment: 'He is come' is old-fashioned, bordering on archaic, but not really dialect. See here [Young Lochinvar is come, or is he? (Grammarphobia)](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/01/is-come.html) - I wanted to be sure that the quoted examples came from e.g. dialogue in old or period-set literature, or whether they were something heard in a Youtube video by an unknown person before giving an answer, which I shall, I now think, not do.

Comment: Of course, because you are plain wrong. It was said in a movie of 2006 by a contemporary person. It's not archaic at all.